# How to align right a inline element in Semantic UI?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/shadyabhi/pen/XyWpKY

I can't get the "icon" to move to the right top of the container.

```
<div class="ui grid">
<div class="ui row results-row">
  <div v-if="isResults" class="ui one wide column">
    <div class="ui raised text container segment column">
      <a class="ui black ribbon label large">Origin</a>
      <i class="fitted icon code"></i>
      <pre class="ui container"><code>{{ result['origin_yaml'] }}</code></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how I want it to look like. Basically, apply this property but in a Semantic UI way:

```
float: right;
```

I've tried applying `ui right floated` classes with no success.

[image]

Comment: you can add custom css code `.fitted{position: absolute;right: 10px;}` It works i guess

Comment: Idea was to use semantic ui for accomplishing this.

Comment: the icon is a ::before and it's not available as a float right in the style sheet to do it in a semanitic way https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.css

Comment: Try using ui right aligned